# Erro no MySQLi INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Não estou sabendo identificar o erro. Sempre montei estruturas assim, mas agora fica aparecendo esse erro.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING)

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUE (
          $_POST['nome'],
          $_POST['sobrenome'],
          $_POST['email'],
          password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n",
          $_POST['contrata'],
          $_POST['trabalha'],
          'N'
    )");
```

> ESTOU USANDO ESSAS VERSÕES:
>
> PHP = 7.1.6
>
> MySQL = 5.7.11

Comment: @Inkeliz São assuntos diferentes, erros diferentes.

Comment: Troca esse pedaço `PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n",` por `PASSWORD_DEFAULT),`

Comment: @rray Erro permanece.

Comment: Faça um log desse seu `insert`, copie e rode no PHP MyAdmin ou no próprio console do MySQL para identificar mais facilmente o erro que está retornando...

Comment: @wBB Como monto o log?

Comment: Você salva essa sua sentença SQL toda numa variável e manda imprimir na tela mesmo, com `echo`: `$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUE (
          $_POST['nome'],
          $_POST['sobrenome'],
          $_POST['email'],
          password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)."\n",
          $_POST['contrata'],
          $_POST['trabalha'],
          'N'
    )"` e executa `echo $sql;` em seguida. Aí você vai ver exatamente o que está enviando para o banco de dados.

Comment: também pode imprimir no console: `echo '<script>console.log('.$sql.')</script>';`

Comment: Tenta dar um echo da sql montada para ver o resultado

Comment: Acho que sua query está errada não? é VALUES no plural

Comment: E a concatenação dos arrays dentro das aspas duplas é assim: {$_POST['nome']}

Comment: Por favor não duplique perguntas, isso é totalmente errado de se fazer na comunidade. Obrigado por compreender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concatenação dos arrays dentro das aspas duplas está incorreta. O PHP não entende funções e arrays que estejam dentro de aspas duplas como variáveis. A maneira correta é concatenar com chaves: `{$_POST['chave']}` ou dessa maneira: `"string".$_POST['chave']."string";`

Outra observação, sua query está como VALUE e o correto é VALUES no plural.

Resultado:

```
$senha = password_hash($_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastro (nome, sobrenome, email, senha, contrata, trabalha, status) VALUES (
       {$_POST['nome']},
       {$_POST['sobrenome']},
       {$_POST['email']},
       $senha,
       {$_POST['contrata']},
       {$_POST['trabalha']},
       'N'
      )";

    echo $sql;
```

Segue [Aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2aa070d2c8e3d1f8e1ab0fedae3012e4e8e185c4) um link para o Sandbox